# Как добавить дополнительные данные в объект если ключ уже есть JS

Tags: javascript

Есть массив вида

```
0:{questionId: "1", answerId: "1"}
1:{questionId: "2", answerId: "4"}
2:{questionId: "2", answerId: "6"}
3:{questionId: "3", answerId: "8"}
```

Получаю я его в цикле

```
        $('input:checked, input[type="input"]', '.card-body').each(function () {
            userAnswers.push({
                questionId: $(this).attr('name'),
                answer: $(this).val(),

            });
        });
```

А нужно, чтобы массив получился таким

```
0:{questionId: "1", answerId: "1"}
1:{questionId: "2", answerId: "4, 6"}
2:{questionId: "3", answerId: "8"}
```

То есть, чтобы по ключу `questionId` он схлопнулся.

Не могу приложить как это сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const tmp = {};
$('input:checked, input[type="input"]', '.card-body').each(function() {
  let name = $(this).attr('name');
  if (tmp.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    tmp[name].push($(this).val());
  } else {
    tmp[name] = [$(this).val()];
  }
});

const userAnswers = [];
for (let k in tmp) {
  if (tmp.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
    userAnswers.push({
      questionId: k,
      answer: tmp[k].join(',')
    });
  }
}
console.log(userAnswers);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-body">
  <input type="checkbox" name="1" value="1" checked>
  <input type="checkbox" name="2" value="4" checked>
  <input type="checkbox" name="2" value="6" checked>
  <input type="checkbox" name="3" value="8" checked>
</div>
```